# Decomposing the numerator and the denominator polynomials into their even and odd parts

Tags: matlab, complex-numbers

Here there is a continues time transfer function `(G(s))` in form of:

```
G(s) = N(s)/D(s);
G(s) = (s^3+4s^2-s+1)/(s^5+2s^4+32s^3+14s^2-4s+50)     (1)
```

and `(s = j*w)` where `w = frequency symbol.`

Now, how is it possible to decompose the numerator and the denominator
polynomials of Eq. (1) into their even and odd parts and get the `G(jw)` as (Using Matlab) :

[image]

Comment: This is not, in fact, a programming question.

Comment: You can define your transfer function G like this: `s = tf('s')
; G = (s^3+4*s^2-s+1)/(s^5+2*s^4+32*s^3+14*s^2-4*s+50);`. `[p,z] = pzmap( G )` gives you the poles and zeros. Does that help?

Comment: Unfortunately No. This method just give poles and zeros of Z form transfer function .Ne , No ,De and Do is important for me (related to W square).

Comment: So is it about getting the even and odd coefficients, i.e. j^2n = -+1 and j^2n+1=+-j?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could probably take the real and imaginary parts after the substitution with `s=j*w`. However, you can actually select the even and odd parts of your polynomials:

```
% G(s) = N(s)/D(s);

syms s;
N = s^3+4*s^2-s+1;

p = sym2poly(N);

%// do this in fewer lines:
%{
/*
if mod(length(p),2)==0  %// then first index is odd
    imin_o = 1;  %// for odd part
    imin_e = 2;  %// for even part
else
    imin_o = 2;  %// for odd part
    imin_e = 1;  %// for even part
end
*/
%} 
imin_o = mod(length(p),2) + 1;
imin_e = 2 - mod(length(p),2);

% odd part of numerator
p_o = zeros(size(p));
p_o(imin_o:2:end) = p(imin_o:2:end);
% even part of numerator
p_e = zeros(size(p));
p_e(imin_e:2:end) = p(imin_e:2:end);

% restore
N_o = poly2sym(p_o,s);
N_e = poly2sym(p_e,s);
```

and the same for the denominator.

Comment: Dear Deak , Is it possible to solve this problem for s=j*w too ?

Comment: @Thomas how about substituting `s=jw` into the result?:) Anyway, if `w` is real, as it usually is, then `N_e` is simply `real(N)` and `N_o` is `imag(N)/w` if I'm not mistaken.